# Is there a downloadable git client for Linux without the need to install it?

Tags: git, command

I'd like to use a git client in a product I'm shipping.

The problem is that the machine on which my product is installed doesn't have git installed. Installing it requires a big bureaucratic effort, which I'd like to avoid.

**Is there a single git binary that can run on all linux 64bit distributions?**

In git's [official site](https://git-scm.com/download/linux), I couldn't find such an option - just installation instruction for different package managers and Linux flavors.

There are many Linux apps that provide a single executable for all Linux distributions, for example, [Sublime](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3143_x64.tar.bz2). Any idea why Git is different?

Comment: google for "git statically linked". I get several relevant results.

Comment: @Patrick thanks. "googled" for "git statically linked" and found issues with linking to libcurl.

Comment: The closest I found was [this](https://github.com/EXALAB/git-static), but it hasn't been updated in 2 years. Also because `git` started out as hacky shell scripts it's still organised as a mountain of separate commands rather than a single `git` binary. Actually some commands still *are* hacky shell scripts. Probably the only reasonable option is to build from source. :-/

Comment: Actually it's not too hard to statically compile Git yourself, but there are some issues - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66987645/265521).

Answer (score -2):

There's an unofficial [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) of [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/): https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases

Just follow the instructions:

```
# Download it
wget https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases/download/release-1.1.1/GitHubDesktop-linux-x86_64-1.1.1.AppImage

# Make it executable
chmod u+x GitHubDesktop-linux-x86_64-1.1.1.AppImage

# Run it (you can also double-click it)
./GitHubDesktop-linux-x86_64-1.1.1.AppImage
```

It should look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank, but I'm looking for a general `GIT` client that's compatible with any GIT repo - not just github.

Comment: How does this answer the question?